# Laravel 4.2: Test Case Autoloading

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Right now when I setup a new test for my Laravel application, it extends from the base `TestCase` class

```
class SomeTest extends TestCase
{
}
```

I'd like to create a new base test class named `AnotherTestCase`, so I can create test cases that share setup/teardown/helper methods/etc...

```
class SomeTest extends AnotherTestCase
{
}
```

However, when I run

```
phpunit app/tests/SomeTest.php
```

I get the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AnotherTestCase' not found in /[...]/app/tests/SomeTest.php on line 3
```

This is despite the fact I have a class defined at

```
#File: app/tests/AnotherTestCase.php
<?php
class AnotherTestCase extends TestCase
{
}
```

This is confusing, since phpunit seems to automatically load the `TestCase` class.

Do I need to manually require in custom base test classes, or is there a way to tell phpunit about my new base test class?  Put another way, why does phpunit automatically load `TestCase`, but doesn't automatically load `AnotherTestCase`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get around this error by adding this to your `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/filters",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/tests/AnotherTestCase.php"  // <-- Add Me
    ],
// ...
```

Afterwards be sure you do a `composer dump-autoload`.  I just tested this by adding the following class:

```
class AnotherTestCase extends TestCase {}
```

And changed one of my existing tests to use this as its parent, instead.  I believe that entry in `composer.json` is how you are able to load `TestCase`.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  For future readers, in case it's not obvious from the question, Laravel ships with app/tests/TestCase.php in its composer.json file.  That's what autoloads the second test case.

Comment: no problem. glad I could return the favor for all my magento questions I had :)